# TeamCity Remote Run "Please Select at least one build configuration"

Tags: visual-studio-2005, teamcity

When i run "Run Personal Build" from the TeamCity addin to visual studio 2005 it appears to connect correctly as i can use the my changes to show my additions. However, in the Personal build window, the right window (i'm guessing that this is where you'd select a build configuration is blank) And as such, i cannot select a build configuration to light up the RUN buttion.

I've verified that the path to svn.exe is correct (detected) and i'm using my explicit login creds.

I've also been flipping through the manual but am not finding the appropriate information easily. (although i'm fairly certain i'm just looking for it wrong)

Anyone else have this problem? what else should i be looking for?

As a note, this machine had a copy of VisualSVN installed which has since expired.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some more troubleshooting and it appears that no one else has this problem, increasing my permissions on the teamcity server seemed to correct my problem.